# Fuzzymatcher library - how to interpret the similarity score?

Tags: python, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-comparison

I am currently using the [fuzzy_matcher](https://github.com/RobinL/fuzzymatcher) library, and have tested it by linking various records.

However i can't figure out the scoring system.

I have used the more popular `fuzzy wuzzy` library before, which scores similarity between 0 and 100 and is easy to automate threshold cutoffs.

With the `fuzzy matcher` library, the similarity score includes negative numbers, and my google-fu can't find out what the range of the score is.

For example, I might have similarity scores from `-0.78` to `1.9`.

Another test I ran had scores from `-0.7` to `1.15`.

Does anybody recognize this scoring system? Is it from negative 2 to plus 2? I can't automate threshold cutoffs if I don't know the maximum or minimum score.

Comment: Agreed. This was asked on the developers git for the package 5 months ago and still has no answer. At this point probably will never get one. Sad because it’s much more user friendly than fuzzy_wuzzy.

Comment: That was me who asked it :) Have you figured it out since you posted this comment?

Comment: No, but i have seen the +/- goes as high as 3.95 now.